# adding 3d model on SCNView

Tags: 3d, scenekit, collada

I've started to build a super-puper game :) using SceneKit and there is one thing I can't decide.

So ... I used third party tools to create a 3d model and then export it in .dae file, after that I add .dae file on SCNView.

For example lets say I need to add 2 3d models on SCNView. As I see there are two ways to add 3d models from .dae file on SCNView:

1 - create one .dae file with two models in it and then add one scene on SCNView

2 - export each 3d model in separate .dae file and the add two .dae files on SCNView

I think that both ways are working good but I want to know if there is best practices to add several 3d models from .dae file on SCNView.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the kind of models you have, both are good options.

If you have a lot of categories of models, such as characters, environment, props etc., I would go for one file each. It's not the most optimized way but it'll save you a lot of time while creating and editing assets.

If you work with what could be a single Spritesheet in 2D, such as parts of a road, a collection of buildings, rollercoaster tracks; I would make a single file and query the nodes I need from it.

It's more about how convinient it is for you, since it won't matter after loading and preparing the Scene.

Answer (score 0):

I try to limit the number of .dae files, but I still use more then one.

If you are planning to export any textures together with your .dae file it's probably good to try and limit the number of .dae files just to make it simpler to maintain (and reuse) any of the image files used as textures. I would use the .dae file

I use one .dae file for "static" world, and when I read this one I make a .flattenedClone() for optimization.

Then I pick dynamical objects from other .dae files like:
(example code only)

```
let importedDae = SCNScene(named: "3d.scnassets/units.dae")!
let warrior = importedDae.rootNode.childNodeWithName(
    "Warrior", recursively: true)!.clone() as! SCNNode
myRealGameScene.rootNode.addChildNode(warrior)
```

I personally prefer to create and control my own SCNScene object, and use the imported .dae files more like libraries, each file grouping objects of the same kind.